# Classification of principally polarized abelian surfaces - reference request

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, abelian-varieties

I found in Encyclopedia of math

https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Abelian_surface

there is a claim that:

"A principally polarized Abelian surface $(A,λ)$ is either the Jacobi variety $J(H)$ of a smooth projective curve $H$ of genus $2$, and $λ=θ$ is the class of the theta divisor, or $A$ is the product of two elliptic curves with $λ$ the product polarization."

It seems to be a well-known result, I wonder if there is any book/note/paper with more details on that claim?

Comment: You just look at the theta-divisor --- either it is a genus 2 curve, then $A$ is its Jacobian, or it is the union of two elliptic curves, then $A$ is their product.

Comment: See Birkenhake-Lange, Corollary 11.8.2. The question would be more appropriate at MSE.